# What is the name of this almost triangular shaped 3x5 Technic beam?

Tags: piece-information, technic

Okay so, I've been on BrickOwl.com for the past day or two, trying to find the names of the pieces for a [LEGO GLaDOS that this guy](https://youtu.be/BPCCsYUgj2I?t=769) made because he doesn't give the names, at around 12:50 he uses this piece:

[image: This one]

and then he also uses some pins shortly after. Does anyone know the name, number, or a place I can buy one or two of the piece and/or the pins?
Or do you have a BrickOwl wishlist with all of the items on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That piece is called a Triangel: http://brickset.com/parts/6010864
You can buy it from the [Lego store](http://shop.lego.com/en-GB/Pick-A-Brick-ByTheme) (no direct link, but it is element id 6010864).

Comment: I think the spelling on Brickset is wrong. Bricklink calls it a Triangle lift arm.

Comment: It's called a Triangel on the Lego store as well.

Comment: I call it a hanger piece, to me it looks like a clothes hanger.

Answer (score 4):

The piece you are looking for is [2905](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2905#T=C) Technic, Liftarm Triangle Thin. There is similar Technic piece with similar looks and same functionality - [99773](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=99773#T=C) - Technic, Liftarm Triangle Thin, Type II

Difference is clearly seen on this image:

[image]